# Angular ng-repeat doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I load the index.html page on local host by hitting localhost:3000/#/ . I can see the template is getting loaded in the network tab of the browser and I can also see that the controller is working fine in the console(by logging). 
However, the page remains blank. To my surprise if I append anything after the url like localhost:3000/#/xyz and refreshes I can see the whole page loads perfectly.

Here is my code of routing:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers',
  'ui.router'
]).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashCtrl'
    })
});
```

When the page remains blank, I can see the nothing inside the class wrap of template while loading the page.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div ng-repeat="category in results track by $index" class="box"> 
    <a href="#/list/{{category.get('categoryName')}}">  
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try hitting just  localhost:3000/

Comment: routeProvider adds a #/ in the URL and it is necessary to keep track of the state when the route changes. See this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/7X1xMxY2Af0

Comment: are you sure this is right? `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/');` ?

Comment: have you tried to use `ui-sref` directive instead of classic `href` attribute

Answer (score 1):

If your data is coming from some service, you can try using `$scope.$apply()` in your service success call back function once you set data on your scope variable.

This will bind the data to your view.

Comment: Perfect..Data binding was the problem. Thank :)